# Responsive table won't react to PHP, but it reacts to HTML

Tags: php, html

I put PHP codes inside my HTML table. This makes table don't work again. It search status will not work, and show entries won't change, beside that, after what I get 11 datas inside the table, it will show only 10 in it and won't create page two.

But, If I put manually with HTML, it works fine. What's the problem? If I create manually inside HTML 's it works fine.

```
   include_once 'info.php';  

    $query = $config -> prepare("SELECT `banID`, `user_banned`, `ban_reason`, `ban_time`, `user_banner`, `ban_timestamp` FROM `samp_ban` ORDER BY `banID` DESC LIMIT 10");  
    if($query -> execute())  
    {  
        $query_results = $query->fetchAll();

    }  foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) { 
    if($query_result["ban_time"] == 0) { $query_result["ban_time"] = "Permanent"; }}
        ?>

    <div class="contentpanel">

      <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-quirk">
        <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home mr5"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="basic-tables.html">Non Grata List</a></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Non GrataLIST</h4>
          <p>Here's the non grata list.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="dataTable1" class="table table-bordered table-striped-col">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>USER</th>
                  <th>REASON</th>
                  <th>TIME</th>
                  <th>ADMIN</th>
                  <th>DATA</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
<?php foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) { 
                        if($query_result["ban_time"] == 0) { $query_result["ban_time"] = "Permanent"; } ?>  

              <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $query_result["banID"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $query_result["user_banned"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $query_result["ban_reason"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $query_result["ban_time"]; ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $query_result["user_banner"];  ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $query_result["ban_timestamp"];  ?></td>
        </tr><?php } ?>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- panel -->


    </div><!-- contentpanel -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see that might be problematic with this code is that you open the table body tag in the foreach loop, but close it outside of the loop. So I would suggest opening you table body tag before the foreach loop:

```
              <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) { 
                 if($query_result["ban_time"] == 0) { $query_result["ban_time"] = "Permanent"; } ?>
               <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $query_result["banID"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $query_result["user_banned"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $query_result["ban_reason"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $query_result["ban_time"]; ?> </td>
                  <td><?php echo $query_result["user_banner"];  ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $query_result["ban_timestamp"];  ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
```